# C# Regular Expression File Parsing Test

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I'm asking for the wisdom of the stackoverflow community. I'm working on a test given to me. I'm using C#, I need to read in a text file that contains commercial flight information. This text file is as follows:

```
 1   AA2401  F7 A4 Y7 B7 M7 H7 K7 /DFW A LAX 4  0715    0836  E0.M80 9 3:21 
 2  AA2421 F7 A1 Y7 B7 M7 H7 K7 DFWLAX 4  1106    1215  E0.777 7     3:09
 3UA:US6352  B9 M9 H9 K0 /DFW 1 LAX    1200  1448  E0.733       1:48
 4   AA2407  F7 A6 Y7 B7 M7 H7 K7 /DFW A LAX 4  0820    0936  E0.757 6 3:16 *
 5   UA 499  F7 Y9 B9 M9 H9 Q9 V9 /DFW B LAX 7  0840    0959  E0.319 4 3:19
 6   UA 448  M9 H9 Q9 V9 /DFW 1 LAX    1200  1448  E0.733 8     1:48 /
 7UA:US6376  B9 M9 H9 K9 /DFW 1 LAX    1315  1603  E0.735       1:48
 8  AA2883 F7 A6 Y7 B7 M7 H7 K7 DFWLAX 4  1215    1328  E0.757 9     3:13
 9UA:US6440  B9 M9 H9 K9 /DFW 1 LAX    1445  1732  E0.735       1:47 /E
10   UA1584  M9 H9 Q9 V9 /DFW   LAX    1445  1732  E0.735 9     1:47
11   UA1082  M9 H9 Q9 V9 /DFW   LAX    1450  1735  E0.735 8     1:45
12   UA 662  M9 H9 Q9 V9 /DFW 1 LAX    1315  1603+1E0.735 N     1:48 /E
13   DL 333  F9 A9 Y9 B9 M9 H9 Q9 /DFW E LAX 5  0930    1046  E0/738 8 3:16
14   AA2413  F7 A7 Y7 B7 M7 H7 K7 /DFW A LAX 4  1008    1124  E0.757 8 3:16
15  DL1435 F9 A9 Y9 B9 M9 H9 Q9 DFWLAX 5  1130    1250-1E0/738 9     3:20
16UA:US6392  B9 M9 H9 K9 /DFW   LAX    1450  1735  E0.735       1:45
17   F9 436  B4 Y4 K4 M4  DFW 1 LAX    1525  1810+1E0.733       1:45 *
18   HP 497  W4 B7 Q7 L7  DFW 1 LAX    1700  1943+1E0.319 N     1:43
```

Given this text file, the information contains the following columns:

```
LineNumber
Carrier
OperatingCarrier
FlightNumber
Classes
DepartureAirport
ArrivalAirport
DepartureTime
ArrivalTime
ArrivalTimeShift
Equipment
Ontime
Duration
```

I also given these two examples:

```
For Line 3:
3          LineNumber
UA        Carrier
US        OperatingCarrier
6352     FlightNumber
BMHK   Classes
DFW      DepartureAirport
LAX     ArrivalAirport
1200     DepartureTime
1448     ArrivalTime
           ArrivalTimeShift
733       Equipment
           Ontime
1:48      Duration


For line 18:
18         LineNumber
HP        Carrier
           OperatingCarrier
497       FlightNumber
WBQL   Classes
DFW      DepartureAirport
LAX     ArrivalAirport
1700     DepartureTime
1943     ArrivalTime
+1        ArrivalTimeShift
319       Equipment
N          Ontime
1:43      Duration
```

I was also directed to make use of regular expressions. Trying to parse this has been a nightmare due to the variance in each line, especially with the spaces. I'm just looking for ideas on how to start tackling this beast. I know I can get rid of the /'s, the :'s, and the *'s.

Thanks.

Comment: _I'm working on a test given to me_ : Looking for answers here is called _Cheating_!

Comment: In addition to Mrchief's comment, if you were allowed to get outside help on the test, you should still start with telling the community what you have tried so far rather than just giving us your test question.

Comment: How do you parse line number versus carrier code situations where the carrier is like Pinnacle who's 9E or (Colgan, 9L) operating a flight for DL?

Comment: What I'm thinking is using 2 spaces as a delimiter between each field. I replace any places that have 3 or more spaces in a row with 2 spaces. Also using regular expressions to get rid of the special characters that I know I don't need (i.e. the /,:,*). Is there an easier way than looping through the string to find the first nonnumeric index? Just so I can parse out the line number by finding the first character that's not a number.

Comment: What about `199E:DL2187`, is that line 199 carrier code E? Nope. It's line 19 carrier code 9E (Pinnacle) on Delta metal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take it a step at a time. For example:

```
`^`         start of line
` *`        possible leading spaces
`(\d+)`     capture the LineNumber
` *`        possible spaces
`([A-Z]+)`  capture the Carrier
```

and so on.

Comment: IATA codes for carriers are `[A-Z0-9]{2}`.

Comment: I actually took your advice and just took it step by step. It turned out to be one of the meanest regular expressions I've ever seen. The group feature inside regular expressions is really what I was missing. That's what made it really easy to parse out. I also used the Espresso regex tool to create it. That was immensely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be fair to give you the answer, but some gentle guidance is considered ok in this community, I believe...
What do you know about regular expressions? Have you looked at some simple examples of what you can parse out with them?
What patterns can you see in the text file? Yes, there are strange variations in the lines, but there is rhyme to the reason. Our human brains do the calculations and pattern recognition so quickly that we forget that there's a simple algorithm underneath. Just tackle each field separately.
Start by learning how to do regex in C#, if you haven't yet. (It's not that hard once you get the basics, but regex is definitely a new concept that can take a bit to wrap your brain around if you haven't before.)
I hope that helps somewhat -- let us know what you've tried so far.

Comment: Thanks, guidance is really what I'm seeking. I do know how to write regular expressions. I don't really have a problem with that. I don't know how to capture parts of a string using the regular expression. As @MRAB suggested, I can take it piece by piece, how do I get those parts pulled out using the regex?

Comment: Check out the Examples section on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) for a quick look at how to pull out strings using C# regex.